# Hide Cognitive Service Key in client side?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using [Azure Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/cognitive-services)(Speech service). I want to hide the Subscription Key on the client side. Is there any way to achieve this goal in Azure? Can I create a function app to act as an intermediate backend?or some other else?

Comment: Do you mean Cognitive Search?

Comment: i mean Speech service,it expose the key for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything client side is never truly hidden. You can try and hide it and it will keep honest people from trying to find it, but if someone really wants it, they will be able to find it. Auth keys should never be in a client app. Besides the security issue, it also makes it difficult to rotate the keys should they ever be compromised.

I highly recommend creating a simple proxy service (Azure function can be used). You would send the query to this proxy service and this service would connect to Azure cognitive services. This way the auth details stay within your subscription. You could then store the key in Azure Key vault for added security. https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial You would then decide if you want the Azure function to require auth depending on your scenario.